# Permutations given a set of characters and length

Tags: c++, algorithm, cartesian-product

Beginner programmer here, just wanted to know if there is an easier way to permute a user given set of characters and a user given length. E.g. A,B with length 3 would be: AAA, ABA, ABB, AAB, BBB, BAB, BAA.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: It is not permutation but Cartesian product. `{A, B}x{A, B}x{A, B}`.

Answer (score 1):

This output corresponds to binary representation of integers 0..7 (000,001, 010 etc), so you can just make for-loop upto `2^N-1`, represent loop counter in binary and substitute zeros and ones with characters.

The same is true for larger char sets (size `M`) - but you have to represent value `0..M^N - 1` in `M`-ary system (using integer division and remainders). Pseudo code:

```
for i = 0 to Power(M, N) - 1 do
   // represent i in M-ary system:
      tmp = i
      for k = 0 to N - 1 do
          digit[k] = tmp % M         //integer modulo
          tmp = tmp / M              //integer division
```

Alternative implementation - traverse all `m^n` values using approach like old electric counter wheels. Python demo code:

```
src = "abc";
M = len(src)
N = 2
l = [0]*N
i = 0
while i < N:
    print([src[x] for x in l])
    i = 0
    l[i] += 1
    while (i < N) and l[i] >= M:
        l[i] = 0
        i += 1
        if i < N:
            l[i] += 1
```